# Wrong Definition of a Limit

Tags: calculus, limits

What would this mean:

> $\exists \delta >0$ such that $\forall \epsilon > 0$ and $\forall x$ satisfying $0 < |x-a| < \delta$, then $|f(x)-L| < \epsilon$

I am pretty confused by the symbols too...

Here's I read it:

There exists a delta larger than zero such that for any epsilon larger than zero and for any $x$ satisfying $0 < |x − a| < \delta$, we will have $|f(x) − L| < \epsilon$.

Does this show that there simply exists an interval where $f(x)$ is a constant function?

Comment: Yes....it does.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Sivaram, I hope this helps people who look at this in the future!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely it would mean $f$ is constant, and equal to $L$, on a neighborhood of radius $\delta$ about $a$.  If you write $\forall\varepsilon>0\ \exists\delta>0$ rather than the other way around, then it is a weaker assertion: that $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)=L$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Specifically it implies $f(x)=L$ on some interval $(a-\delta,a+\delta)$.  This is because the statement says that $f(x)$ is *arbitrarily* close to $L$ for $x$ within this interval (since we can choose $\epsilon>0$ as small as we desire), and in the real numbers arbitrarily close means equality.

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't pick your answer - his came first :( Thank you so much though!

Comment: @anon How can arbitrarily close imply equality, especially given the fact that $\varepsilon > 0$ ?

Comment: @curryage Isn't it extremely obvious? Can you think of two real numbers that are arbitrarily close but distinct? Do you know what "arbitrarily close" means?

Comment: @anon Ok. Makes sense.

Answer (score -2):

Not really. f(x) is still the function itself - it does not **become** a constant function.

What it says is that if you select an appropriate δ (often small enough), you can get the distance to f(x) smaller than any ε. Very often δ is built on ε, been restricted to the f:=x relationship, the difference between f(x) and L is always smaller than ε. Now L is the limit, meaning you are close enough to f(x), but you are not **at the point** of (x, f(x)).

Comment: Note that OP has written the usual limit definition with the $\forall\epsilon>0$ and $\exists\delta>0$ backwards.